# mysql node Select query with JSON information on WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, nodes

Referring to this documentation example

```
 connection.query(**'INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {   
   if (err) throw err;     
   console.log(result.insertId); 
 });
```

I'm trying to perform a query like this

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE ? , [ title : "a",  publisher : "aa" ]
```

But it doesn't work because it writes a "," to separate the fields from default. Do you know a possible solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate the fields and pass the values as array:

```
connection.query('SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE title=? AND publisher=?', [title_value, publisher_value], function(err, result) { 
    if (err) throw err;    
    console.log(result); 
});
```

[Docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)